# What is the permission necessary to drop a service in service-broker?

Tags: permissions, errors, service-broker

When I want to drop a service which is already created, this error happens:

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 316
Cannot drop the service '//Audit/Contract', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

My sql query to perform drop operation is:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.service_contracts  WHERE NAME = '//Audit/Contract')
    DROP SERVICE [//Audit/Contract]
```

So, the main question is: **What is the permissions necessary to drop a service in service-broker?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I post this question, I just found my answer with some tricky way. I went to the left object explorer and delete the contract with it. but instead of submitting the form I click on the script button which produces the scripts. It was my mistake to drop a contract with `drop service` command. so the correct query to drop a contract is:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.service_contracts  WHERE NAME = '//Audit/Contract')
    DROP CONTRACT [//Audit/Contract]
```

I post this answer because maybe somebody encounter with this error and my guide can be useful to him/her.